# Python string grouping?

Tags: python, grouping, chunks

Basically, I print a long message but I want to group all of those words into 5 character long strings.
For example ***"iPhone 6 isn’t simply bigger — it’s better in every way. Larger, yet dramatically thinner."*** I want to make that 
***"iPhon 6isn' tsimp lybig ger-i t'sbe terri never yway. Large r,yet drama tical lythi nner. "***

Comment: `''.join(s.split())` and then http://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/2301450

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @vaultah, this is achieved by splitting the string by a space and joining them back without spaces; then using a for loop to append the result of a slice operation to an array. An elegant solution is to use a comprehension.

```
text = "iPhone 6 isn’t simply bigger — it’s better in every way. Larger, yet dramatically thinner."
joined_text = ''.join(text.split())
splitted_to_six = [joined_text[char:char+6] for char in range(0,len(joined_text),6)]
' '.join(splitted_to_six)
```

I'm sure you can use the re module to get back dashes and apostrophes as they're meant to be

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the following.

```
import re
sentence="iPhone 6 isn't simply bigger - it's better in every way. Larger, yet dramatically thinner."
sentence  = re.sub(' ', '', sentence)
count=0
new_sentence=''
for i in sentence:
    if(count%5==0 and count!=0):
        new_sentence=new_sentence+' '
    new_sentence=new_sentence+i
    count=count+1
```

print new_sentence

Output:

```
iPhon e6isn 'tsim plybi gger- it'sb etter ineve ryway .Larg er,ye tdram atica llyth inner .
```